# Conditional statement and split in a Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement, dataframe, split

I am looking for a conditional statement in python to look for a certain information in a specified column and put the results in a new column

Here is an example of my dataset:

```
OBJECTID    CODE_LITH
1              M4,BO
2              M4,BO
3              M4,BO
4              M1,HP-M7,HP-M1
```

and what I want as results:

```
OBJECTID    CODE_LITH           M4   M1
1              M4,BO            1    0
2              M4,BO            1    0
3              M4,BO            1    0
4              M1,HP-M7,HP-M1   0    1
```

What I have done so far:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
lookup = ['M4']
df.loc[df['CODE_LITH'].str.isin(lookup),'M4'] = 1
df.loc[~df['CODE_LITH'].str.isin(lookup),'M4'] = 0
```

Since there is multiple variables per rows in "CODE_LITH" it seems like the script in not able to find only "M4" it can find "M4,BO" and put 1 or 0 in the new column

I have also tried:

```
if ('M4') in df['CODE_LITH']: 
    df['M4'] = 0
else:
    df['M4'] = 1
```

With the same results.

Thanks for your help.

PS. The dataframe contains about 2.6 millions rows and I need to do this operation for 30-50 variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is the Pythonic way to do it:

```
for mn in ['M1', 'M4']: # Add other "M#" as needed
    df[mn] = df['CODE_LITH'].map(lambda x: mn in x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19.1/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) accessor:

```
>>>> for key in ('M4', 'M1'):
...      df.loc[:, key] = df['CODE_LITH'].str.contains(key).astype(int)

>>> df
   OBJECTID       CODE_LITH  M4  M1
0         1           M4,BO   1   0
1         2           M4,BO   1   0
2         3           M4,BO   1   0
3         4  M1,HP-M7,HP-M1   0   1
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do:

```
for index,data in enumerate(df['CODE_LITH']):
    if "I1" in data:
        df['Plut_Felsic'][index] = 1
    else:
        df['Plut_Felsic'][index] = 0
```

It does work, but takes quite some time to calculate.